# SQL Type Providers with ROP - F#

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I'm attempting to use Railway Oriented Programming principals http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/ and this http://indiedevspot.azurewebsites.net/2015/01/20/two-track-coding-rop-for-dummies-part-2/ for reference

I have successfully implemented this for most of the codebase, except now we are getting to putting items into SQL and wish to use ROP for validation of those types.  The typical pattern is

Figure 1:

```
let createSomething a b c = {A = a; B = b; C = c}
let createValidSomething so = 
    createSomething
    <!> validateFunction1 so.param1
    <*> validateFunction2 so.param2
    <*> ...so forth and so on
```

You will notice that createSomething is a function that returns a record type instantiation a -> b -> c -> a' -> b' -> c'
The SQL Type providers return a mutable type (non record).  Lets look at my attempt to build a similar createSomething function

Figure 2:

```
    let createSQS(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) =
    let sqs = context.``[dbo].[Something]``.Create(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
    sqs
```

At this point, we know this already will not work, we have a->b->c->d->e->f->g->context.`[dbo].[Something]`.Entity

I know I can have an intermediary record type and follow ROP principals, match on success/failure and then create my object off of the already validated.  But does that not seem like too many steps?

Does anybody know of a good pattern for this?  Ideally we could have a function similar to Figure1 that generates a Record Type that is compatible with the Type Providers.

I'm open to trying things and hanging out on Skype :).

Comment: which SQL type provider do you mean? could you just implement it there by providing another method?

Comment: The FSharp.Data.SQL.SQLDataProvider

Comment: not sure I can provide another method that exposes the type construction in the same manner.  Example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we came up with an answer at our dev meeting, and decided that we in fact WANT to execute each part in its own function.  For the inner binds we invented our own operator; similar to plus (&&&) (which I will blog about on my site [www.indiedevspot.com](http://www.indiedevspot.com)) and at the top level we ran with a normal bind.

Our top level code looks like this:

```
[<HttpPost>]
x.member Add(sa:Something) =
           sa|>ValidateSomething
           >>= converttoSSA
           >>= persistSSA
```

We decided to separate the concerns due to independent testability of validation, conversion and persistence.  The theory is that functional composition if made up of functions that are guaranteed to work, is itself inherently guaranteed to work (or have a much better chance).

If we went with the proposed method (which we have not yet solved), we would be mixing concerns of creation, validation and conversion.  That would also end up creating an additional record type which was un-necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Should your function `createSQS` not be better like this:

```
let createSQS a b c d e f g =
    context.``[dbo].[Something]``.Create(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
```

This one would have the needed signature of `a->b->c->d->e->f->g->context.[dbo].[Something].Entity`

Comment: Ah, so both flavors of the function are in fact returning the exact same thing.  I went ahead and removed the additional code from my flavor.

Comment: The signature we are looking for is: a -> b -> c -> a' -> b' -> c'

Comment: What is the exact signature of createSomething in your example?
If I see it right, it is a->b->c->Foo, where Foo = {A: a; B: b; C: c}.

Comment: see answer below.  createSomething had the signature a -> b -> c -> a' -> b' -> c'